# How do I center my anchor elements in my custom navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to build a custom navigation bar. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

How do I bring each of my anchor element to get in the center of each box (both vertically, and horizontally)? Also, the brand element has a bigger font, but I want a solution which will center all the elements nicely.

In short, I want it to look something like this:

[image]

The borders on the first pic is for testing obviously. I made the second pic with a photoshop edit. My code for this page looks is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Basic Page Needs
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- FONT
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- CSS
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
        <!-- Favicon
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

        <style type="text/css">
            nav.navbar {
                height: 50px;
                margin: 0 0 25px 0;
                background: white;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #d3d3d3;
            }
            ul.navbar-list {
                list-style: none;
                height: 50px;
            }
            ul.navbar-list-left {
                float: left;
            }
            ul.navbar-list-right {
                float: right;
            }
            ul.navbar-list > li.navbar-item {
                display: inline-block;
                height: inherit;
            }

            ul.navbar-list > li.navbar-item > a.navbar-link {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;

                margin-top: 13px;
                margin-right: 15px;

            }

            ul.navbar-list > li.navbar-item > a.navbar-brand-link {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-top: 7px;
                margin-right: 25px;
            }


        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Primary Page Layout
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="navbar-list navbar-list-left navbar-brand-list">
                    <li class="navbar-item navbar-brand-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link navbar-brand-link">BRAND</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-list navbar-list-left">
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="http://professorsreviewbd.com" class="navbar-link">Product</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Company</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-list navbar-list-right">
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Log in</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Sign up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve column">
                    <h4>Basic Page</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum ....
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Document
            –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: I am using [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) for this.

So how do I fix my navbar? These are the things I want:

- The text of each anchor element needs to be centered vertically and horizontally.

  - I want the

    element containing the  element to take up 100% of the height of the navbar.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this css and check, it may help you..

```
<style type="text/css">
    nav.navbar {
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 0 25px 0;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #d3d3d3;
    }
    ul.navbar-list {
        list-style: none;
        height: 50px;
    }
    ul.navbar-list-left {
        float: left;
    }
    ul.navbar-list-right {
        float: right;
    }
    ul.navbar-list > li.navbar-item {
        display: inline-block;
        height: inherit;
    }

    ul.navbar-list > li.navbar-item > a.navbar-link {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;

        margin-right: 15px;

    }

    ul.navbar-list > li.navbar-item > a.navbar-brand-link {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }


</style>
```